# String index out of range: -1.

Tags: java, substring, indexoutofboundsexception, indexoutofrangeexception

I have written a method that takes `html`code stored as a string, and swaps images in this `html`code with images of my choosing. I'm constantly getting a `String index out of range: -1`exception. I dont understand where i could be going out of bounds.Can someone look at my code and give me a hint?

```
    public static String replaceImgs(String htmlCode){
    String finalString = "";
    String toFind = "img src=\"";
    String imgReplace = "img src=\"http://media4.popsugar-assets.com/files/2014/08/08/878/n/1922507/caef16ec354ca23b_thumb_temp_cover_file32304521407524949.xxxlarge/i/Funny-Cat-GIFs.jpg";
    String tagReplace = "\">";
    String rest = "";

    int index = htmlCode.indexOf(toFind);
    String firstString = htmlCode.substring(0, index);

    rest = htmlCode.substring(index+1, htmlCode.length());
    index = rest.indexOf(tagReplace);

    String secondString = rest.substring(index, rest.length());
    finalString = firstString.concat(imgReplace).concat(secondString);
    return finalString;
}
```

Comment: The `-1` should give you a hint. What does `indexOf` return if no match was found?

Comment: Do you know how to debug your code?

Answer (score 1):

The String.indexOf() method returns -1 if not found and you ignore it in your code. Probably is your current problem

BTW, Please note that the method String.substring(begin, end) returns a string starting to begin index (inclusive) until end index (exclusive).

Answer (score 0):

if no occurence are find `indexOf` will return -1

As in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int))